How to perform amplitude amplification when the initial amplitude of aiming state is unknown
Let's say, I want to perform amplitude amplification on the quantum state
$$|s\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}m_i |i\rangle\,,$$
And the aiming state is $|x\rangle\,.$
Usually, when I perform amplitude amplification with the Grover operator
$$G=(2|x\rangle\langle x|-I)H^{\otimes n}(2|0\rangle\langle 0|-I)H^{\otimes n}\,,$$
for $k$ times, the amplitude of $|x\rangle$ become $$\sin(2k\alpha+\alpha_0)\,.$$
We would like $k$ to be something that makes $$2k\alpha+\alpha_0=\frac{\pi}{2}\,.$$ But how can we determine $k$, the number of Grover iterations, when we don't know the initial amplitude of aiming state, i.e. we don't know the value of $\alpha_0$?

I find section 3 of this pdf: https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dieter/Courses/2022s-CS710/Scribes/scribe10.pdf might be useful

Crudely, what you want to do is think of your grover iterator $G$ as a unitary, and your unknown rotation angle $\alpha$ corresponds to two eigenvalues of $G$, $e^{\pm i\alpha}$, and you can prepare an initial state that is a superposition of the two eigenvectors. So, these are all the ingredients that you need in order to perform phase estimation to approximate the angle $\alpha$, and hence the number of steps that you require.
